# Automatically scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an info screen that displays a table of informations which usually is quite long, so I want it to scroll slowly down automatically until it reaches the bottom, fades to white, scroll back up, and fades out from white, repeating the process all over after some delays.

Currently I have this code:

```
var iInterval = 2000;
var iScrollInterval = 5000;
var iFadeInterval = 500;

var loop = function() {
    var iScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: iScroll
    }, {
        duration : iScrollInterval, 
        easing : "linear", 
        complete : function() {
            $("body").fadeOut(iFadeInterval).delay(iFadeInterval);
            $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
            $("body").fadeIn(iFadeInterval);
        }
    });             
    setTimeout(loop, iInterval);
};
setTimeout(loop, iInterval);
```

The problem with that code is that scrolls down to the bottom, immediately jumps to the top again, without fading and keeps scrolling down immediately without delay.

This behavior is repeating 2-3 times until, finally, the fading to/from white happens, once the bottom of the page is reached for the 3rd time.

There's no doubt I've misunderstood something here, but what?

Comment: Your iInterval is shorter than iScrollInterval and therefore another cycle starts before previous one was complete. Try to increase first one beyond second one values.

Comment: So the setTimeout in loop() is run before the animate() completes?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't  been using jQuery for a while, but after looking at your code there is couple of things:

1. Why are you scrolling both HTML and BODY?
2. The page jumps back up because you are not animating it here:

   $("html, body").scrollTop(0);

And al other problems derive from that. If I have a minute I will update my answer with fiddle

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/64etqaxc/1/

```
var iInterval = 2000;
var iScrollInterval = 5000;
var iFadeInterval = 500;

var loop = function() {
    var iScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    $("html").animate({
        scrollTop: iScroll
    }, {
        duration : iScrollInterval, 
        easing : "linear", 
        complete : function() {
            $("body").fadeOut(iFadeInterval, function(){ 
                $("html").scrollTop(0);
                $("body").fadeIn(iFadeInterval,function(){ 
                    loop();
                });
            });            
        }
    });                    
};

loop();
```

Comment: I scroll both html and body for arbitrary reasons, really. Scrolling just HTML would suffice, but the end-result is the same.

The issue is that the fading is NOT executed until the page has scrolled up 3 times or so (it varies, which is what puzzles me the most). There is also supposed to be a delay before it starts scrolling again after the page has scrolled back up, but said delay is only present when the fading is executed.

Comment: @Gipphe do you actually know what you mean when you saying "for arbotrary reasons" ? Because targeting both document and body is messing up almost everything...

Comment: If I removed HTML, the page wouldn't scroll. If I removed BODY, the page would constantly fade in and out to white while scrolling. My apologies for referring to my reasons as "arbitrary", but I saw multiple examples use HTML and BODY in the selector. Nonetheless, your solution almost solved the issue: a delay appears at the end of the downwards scrolling that seems to increase in length as the page repeats the process.

Comment: @Gipphe targetting both will create problems, it will extend delays etc. Better to do a lot of testing to figure out what exactly is hapenning and target the right thing, or create your own environment (dot use body and html but create your own structure). But as I said, I didnt do similar thing for long time so I am not aware of the best practices